# Cant open the Springer llncs downlaod

Tags: discussion

I am trying to download [this](ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip) `llncs` file from Springer.

However it only shows a blank page.
Does somebody know how to get this working?

Comment: That's an `ftp://` address, which modern browsers may not even support anymore (Firefox doesn't, I'm not sure about others). Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to download a zip file so you won't see output in your browser. Check your downloads folder which will probably be named `Downloads` in your home directory. You may need to double click on the file to get to the contents.